# Is there a way to unregister or override the event handler for a dependency property changed callback in a subclass?

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties

i'm using fluent ribbon, which has this class "GalleryItem" that extends ListBoxItem. In this class, an event handler to the IsSelected property changed is registered:

```
IsSelectedProperty.AddOwner(typeof (GalleryItem), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false,FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.None, OnIsSelectedPropertyChanged));
```

Unfortunattely, the event handler has a bug, and i don't want to edit the project source code, naturally, so i've subclassed the GalleryItem to a "CustomGalleryItem" and do the following in the static construction:

```
IsSelectedProperty.AddOwner(typeof(CustomGalleryItem),new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.None, OnIsSelectedPropertyChanged)); }
```

However, both event handlers are called when "IsSelected" changes.. what are my options? (i wish to override the event handler of the "GalleryItem"

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the DependencyProperty.OverrideMetadata() method. This might replace the change handler, rather than simply adding another owner.

Answer (score 0):

This problem has been logged as an issue on the Fluent codeplex page [here](http://fluent.codeplex.com/workitem/19784), and has been solved in release 62947 and up, which can be downloaded [here](http://fluent.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets)